# /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11:

Tags: flutter, dart

The error is occuring as

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:112:15: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:19:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:22:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_platform_interface-4.1.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

put this package firebase_auth_platform_interface with this version 6.2.0 in your apps's pubspec.yaml as a dependency override, hope it help you.

Comment: No its not working, Any other way

Comment: it worked for me, do you have any other details?